# Failed to read maven project in eclipse: For Input String "US"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven project in Eclipse (Neon 2).

My pom.xml of that particular project is giving an error. Whenever I open the pom file in eclipse, an error message is thrown in the Error Log tab. The message is as such --> Failed to read Maven project: For input string: "US".

Double clicking on the error displays the full error message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "US"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.MavenArtifactRepository.decode(MavenArtifactRepository.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.MavenArtifactRepository.basedir(MavenArtifactRepository.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.MavenArtifactRepository.<init>(MavenArtifactRepository.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem.createArtifactRepository(MavenRepositorySystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem.buildArtifactRepository(MavenRepositorySystem.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.initProject(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.initProject(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:679)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$5.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$5.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.execute(ProjectRegistryManager.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.readProjectWithDependencies(ProjectRegistryManager.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.create(ProjectRegistryManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.create(MavenProjectManager.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.actions.SelectionUtil.getMavenProject(SelectionUtil.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.readMavenProject(MavenPomEditor.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor$5.run(MavenPomEditor.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I'm still able to execute mvn clean/install etc... but it's just annoying to keep seeing the pom error in your project. I don't want to simply alter something in maven or eclipse to hide the error i want to understand why it's happening and what's the best way to fix it.

Comment: It's rather not a Maven issue. Please show us your code.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz You mean show you the actual pom.xml, right?

Comment: No. Your .java files. You pass a string to a method that expects a number to be passed.

Comment: My project contains 100s of Java classes let alone thousands of LOCS. If it was a compiler issue, then it would have been shown upon building my project. However, building my project is a success, and class files are generated. The error above is shown when i open the pom file and a red X icon is always displayed on the pom.xml file

Comment: I'd really like to help, but I think it's pure fortune telling, if we do not know your code etc.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I'm pretty sure it's not a code issue. One of my project is simple pom project. No Java classes no nothing. Simply a pom file. That one gives the same error as well. Thanks for your help though

Comment: An absolute wild guess there somewhere is a charset `US-ASCII` without quotes, interpreted as number-minus-number. But cannot guess how.

Comment: @JoopEggen Searched the pom file and there's no occurrence of US

Comment: It could Expression Language, some variable from a properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown here:

> at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.MavenArtifactRepository.decode(MavenArtifactRepository.java:314)

Looking at MavenArtifactRepository's [source code](https://github.com/yangtao309/maven-tutorial/blob/master/maven-source-code/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/MavenArtifactRepository.java), I would *think* you have a repository defined either in your `pom.xml` or in your `settings.xml` with an invalid URL (with the String **US**).

- take a look at your `pom.xml` or parent pom;
- take a look at `settings.xml` (usually in `~/.m2`, though you may have override its location in Eclipse);
- Perhaps it's some repository configured in Eclipse, you could do a full search into your eclipse workspace through eclipse configuration files.

`MavenArtifactRepository`'s relevant source code (read the javadoc comments) :

```
/**
 * Create a remote download repository.
 * @param url the URL of the repository
*/
public MavenArtifactRepository(..., String url, ...) {
    ...
    this.basedir = basedir( url );
}


/**
 * Derive the path portion of the given URL.
 * @param url the repository URL
*/
private String basedir( String url ) {
    if ( protocol.equalsIgnoreCase( "file" ) ) {
        retValue = url.substring( protocol.length() + 1 );
        retValue = decode( retValue );
    ...
}

/**
 * Decodes the specified (portion of a) URL. <strong>Note:</strong> This decoder assumes that ISO-8859-1 is used to
 * convert URL-encoded bytes to characters.
 *
 * @param url The URL to decode, may be <code>null</code>.
 * @return The decoded URL or <code>null</code> if the input was <code>null</code>.
 */
private static String decode( String url )
{
    String decoded = url;
    if ( url != null )
    {
        int pos = -1;
        while ( ( pos = decoded.indexOf( '%', pos + 1 ) ) >= 0 )
        {
            if ( pos + 2 < decoded.length() )
            {
                String hexStr = decoded.substring( pos + 1, pos + 3 );
                char ch = (char) Integer.parseInt( hexStr, 16 );
                decoded = decoded.substring( 0, pos ) + ch + decoded.substring( pos + 3 );
            }
        }
    }
    return decoded;
}
```

---

If I read the code right, your **bad** repository probably looks like this:

```
file:anything%USanything
```

Apparently (according to the code), only valid *2-digits hexadecimal* should follow the '%' sign in the url...

Comment: You are right. I had this in my parent pom.xml: file:C:/Users/%USERNAME%/.m2